# SQLite Database Column Error

Tags: android-sqlite

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PROFILES="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_PROFILES+"("+KEY_PROFILE_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            +KEY_NAME+" TEXT," +KEY_EMAIL+" TEXT,"+KEY_PASS+" TEXT,"+KEY_CONTACT+" TEXT,"+KEY_GENDER+" TEXT,"+KEY_LOCATION+" TEXT,"
            +KEY_SALARY+" TEXT,"+KEY_JOBAREA+" TEXT,"+KEY_DIET+" TEXT,"+KEY_DRINK+" TEXT,"+KEY_DOB+" TEXT,"+KEY_RELIGION+
            " TEXT,"+KEY_EDUCATION+" TEXT,"+KEY_DETAIL+" TEXT,"+KEY_PHOTO+" BLOB,"+KEY_CODE+" TEXT,"+KEY_ACTIVE+" TEXT"+")";
And the Error is :
table Profiles has no column named userGender
04-14 03:31:51.815 4595-4595/com.example.appify.matrimonio E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting userName=Natasha userEmail=Natasha@gmail.com userGender=bride userContact=5555 userPass=natasha
                                                                             android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Profiles has no column named userGender (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Profiles(userName,userEmail,userGender,userContact,userPass) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
                                                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
                                                                                 at helper.DatabaseHelper.addProfile(DatabaseHelper.java:84)
                                                                                 at com.example.appify.matrimonio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5249)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2165)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1213)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04

Answer (score 0):

if you changed your table structure, increment value of your database version.
surely it will work.